# How to use MongoDB from Bitnami Wamp Stack?

Tags: php, mongodb, bitnami

I want to use `mongodb` with `php`. I have installed `Binami Wamp Stack 5.6`. `phpinfo()` is working fine but on running the code below, I found this error

> The localhost page isn’t working
>   localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();

   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;

   echo "Database mydb selected";
?>
```

I also tried with `$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");` but same error.

There are two `.dll` of `mongo` named `php_mongo.dll` and `php_mongodb.dll` are already in `php` folder inside `ext` folder. 
 Can some one help me?

Comment: have u included php_mongo.dll in your ext folder?

Comment: @RahulPawar `Bitnami Wamp Stack` has built-in installed `mongo` drivers. Yes! I saw two `.dll` of `Mongo` in `ext` folder.

Comment: Have you tried by restarting the server.

Comment: @RahulPawar Yes. I have restarted it but getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the configuration file php.ini and uncomment the line below:

```
;extension=php_mongodb.dll
```

Removing the `;` at the beggining.

After that, you have to restart Apache. You can use the Bitnami Manager to do that.

Finally, you can check that it is working with this small example:

```
<?php
 // connect to mongodb
 $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
 var_dump($manager); 
?>
```

I hope this information is useful for you. If you have any other question, please do not hesitate to let us know.

Best Regards,

Juan Ariza

Answer (score 0):

1. I have simply downloaded **php_mongo.dll** file and paste in
   **xampp\php\ext**
   folder and
2. open php.ini (config file) and paste "extension=php_mongo.dll" this
   line at bottom of the file.
3. and restart the my xampp server

My db connection as follow

```
function get_db_con() {
    $mongo = new MongoClient();
    $db = $mongo->my_db_name;
    return $db;
}
```

And i called above function like this:

```
function my_function() {

    $db = get_db_con(); // I call function for db connection
}
```

and its working for me!

Comment: Which version of `php_mongo.dll`?

Comment: I think Version 1.5.2 . & my PHP Version 5.4.31

Comment: Which version of Mongo Database?